# angularjs directive to change the format of name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I did not quite understand how to write AngularJS directives even after looking at many blogs. Basically I have an array of names in the format "lastname, firstname". I want to write a directive to make it "firstname lastname"

My html is like this

```
<div ng-repeat="names in nameArray"
    <custom-name-format> {{names}} </custom-name-format>
</div>
```

How do I pass the 'names' parameter to the directive?

controller:

```
angular.module('nameApp').directive('customNameFormat', function() {

    // how do I access and manipulate {{names}} here?
});
```

Comment: $scope.nameArray gives the entire array.... I don't want to change the name format of every element. I want to change the nameformat of only the current "names"  in nameArray

Comment: if there are key:value pairs in the array like {lastname: b, firstname: a}...

...you can show them on screen as:

{{names.firstname}} {{names.lastname}}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use **filter** instead of **directive**.


**Here's the [JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/albertonaperijr/wmk3213s/4/)**.


**Sample Codes**:

**HTML**:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <ul ng-controller="YourCtrl">
       <li ng-repeat="name in names">
           {{name.name | customNameFormat}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('YourCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.names = [
        {name:'Doe, John'},
        {name:'Naperi, Alberto'},
        {name:'Last, First'},
        {name:'Espolon, Justin'},
        {name:'Bor, Em'},
        {name:'Pik, El'},
      ];

}]);

app.filter('customNameFormat', function() {    

    return function(input) {
        var nameStr = input.split(',').reverse().join(' ');
        return nameStr;
    };

});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

I think you don't need a directive here. A filter will be more appropriate. You can also pass the argument to filter easily.

In HTML:

```
{{ filter_expression | filter : expression : comparator}}
```

In JavaScript:

```
$filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator)
```

Answer (score 3):

In the directive

```
angular.module('nameApp').directive('customNameFormat', function() {
  return{
    scope:{
    names : '='
    },
    link: function(scope,elem,attr){
       var nameStr = scope.names //lastname, firstname
       var newNameStr = nameStr.split(',').reverse().join(' ');
       elem.html(newNameStr);

    } 

 }

})

<div ng-repeat="names in nameArray"
   <custom-name-format names="names" ></custom-name-format>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set an attribute for the name like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="names in nameArray">
    <custom-name-format custname="{{names}}"> {{names}} </custom-name-format>
</div>
```

And then access the names of custname in your directive like this:

```
scope: {
  custname: '@'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use jquery as well but in Angular way can access with attributes also

```
<div ng-repeat="names in nameArray"
    <custom-name-format custom-attr="{{name}}"> {{names}} </custom-name-format>
</div>
```

controller:

```
angular.module('nameApp').directive('customNameFormat', function() {

     return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
alert(attrs.customAttr);
}
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex matching to rearrange the name

```
var parts = name.match(/(\w+), (\w+)/)
parts[2] + " " + parts[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this will help you out

```
var demo = angular.module('demo', []);
demo.directive('displayTime', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: false,
        template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="data in datas">{{data.first}}----- {{data.last}}</li></ul>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
          scope.datas = [{first:"pavan",last:"techie"},{first:"sword",last:"fish"}]; 
        }
    }});
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pavanastechie/sZZEt/215/)

Answer (score 0):

**Try to Change your name using AngularJs**

```css
body{
  font-family: 'arial';
}
ul,li{
  list-style: none;
}
ul{
  padding: 0px;
  margin:0px;
}
.name-demo{
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 10px;
}
.name-demo li{
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.name-demo li input{
  border:1px solid #e4e4e4;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<p>Try to Change your name using AngularJs</p>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="name-demo">
    <ul>
      <li>
        First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName">
      </li>
      <li>
        Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName">
      </li>
      <li>
        Full name is: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script>

var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
 $scope.firstName = "Arvinda";
 $scope.lastName = "Kumar";
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```